# Equations of Motion and Minimization of Spacetime Interval

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, variational-principle, equations-of-motion

I'm trying to show that the extrema of a path in spacetime, as given by the spacetime interval (or length if just considering space) is the one that solves the equations of motion.

Let a path be given by coordinates $x^{\mu}(u)$ and parameterized by $u$, with:

$\dot{x}^{\mu}=\frac{dx^{\mu}}{du}$

I know that we can find the equations of motion from a function $f(x, \dot{x})$:

$f=g_{\mu\nu}\dot{x}^{\mu}\dot{x}^{\nu}$

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{\mu}}-\frac{d}{du}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot{x}^{\mu}}=0$

But for any path, our spacetime interval $s$ is given by:

$s=\int du \sqrt{g_{\mu\nu}\dot{x}^{\mu}\dot{x}^{\nu}}=\int du \sqrt{f} $

Which, when varied gives:

$\frac{\delta s}{\delta x^{\mu}(v)}=\int du \frac{1}{2\sqrt{f}}\frac{\delta f}{\delta x^{\mu}(v)}=
\int du \frac{1}{2\sqrt{f}}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{\mu}}\delta(v-u)+
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot{x}^{\mu}}\dot{\delta}(v-u)\right)
=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{f}}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{\mu}}-\frac{d}{dv}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot{x}^{\mu}}\right)
-\left(\frac{d}{dv}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{f}}\right) \frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot{x}^{\mu}}$

Where I integrated by parts and the delta functions turned the $u$'s to $v$'s in the last equation (so that $\dot{}=d/dv$).

I see the first term in my final expression contains the equations of motion, but I am left with a second term. Is there a way I can argue that it is zero, or somehow arbitrarily depends on the parameter so that I can always choose to make it zero?